# Implementing search on an ASP.NET MVC website

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, search, full-text-search

I've created a content-managed website using ASP.NET MVC. All content is stored in the 'Content' table in a SQL Server database, with the text itself stored in a column of datatype 'XML'.

I want to add a search feature to the site that will search all the XML content and return a list of results, each of which links to the content item.

Any ideas on which technology would be most appropriate?

Should I be using SQL Server full-text indexing, or something else such as DotLucene?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Lucene.net](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/) will be a better alternative for you. You can do lot of advanced search through lucene.

Docs @ http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/docs/2.1/

Comment: Can you elaborate why Lucene.net would be better than FTS?

Comment: Lucene offers a richer search experience, such as being able to display the surrounding text in each search result, so the user can see the context in which their search words got picked up, similar to how Google and other search engines work.